# Verify email using mailgun api in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, mailgun

I used the code in [This link](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/user_manual.html#email-validation)
It's showing the error :
"require(vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory"

How can I include the autoload.php file? I couldn't find it in mailgun sdk. And should I really use composer (Which I found in many sites to install composer)? I am using Codeigniter framework.

Please help.Can you please tell me how to use this code in CodeIgniter.

Comment: You need to use composer https://getcomposer.org/. Composer will help you dealing with dependencies and it's basically god send. unfortunately, it requires some basic knowledge of command line. basically you create composer file, run `composer {update|install}` from command line, and it pulls all your dependencies for you.

Comment: Thankyou for the comment :) @MaciejPaprocki

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is simple; you don't have vendor folder. [Click here](https://getcomposer.org/download/) to learn how to download composer to your server. Then [click here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#downloading-the-composer-executable) to get started.

Once you installed composer, you should add required packages in `composer.json` and run composer.

Also you don't need to use `require`. Open `application/config/config.php` file and find `$config['composer_autoload']` variable. Type `'vendor/autoload.php'` instead of `FALSE`.

Comment: Ok thankyou for the answer :) , let me try to do it.

Comment: Just one doubt, where should i place the vendor folder in codeigniter file so that i can give `$config['composer_autoload'] ='vendor/autoload.php'?` is it inside applications?

Comment: Composer will generate it in the same location with composer.json file.

Comment: Ok i got it , just want to know where should i mention the location while generating it.